# MVC @html.Actionlink include html i tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I currently have the following MVC code.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

This generates the following HTML code

```
<li>
    <a href="/"></a>
</li>
```

How Can I obtain the following HTML code?

```
<a href="#">
    <i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>
     Home
</a>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: What stops you from writing the html that you want without using the ActionLink helper?

Comment: @Rui The page would not pass through the home controller..If the home controller ensured users were authenticated and authorised to view the index page we would have a problem. Views that run on user credentials may also not run. Many reasons....

Comment: Peter, it will pass through the home controller. The html helpers just output normal html. In the end, having @Html.ActionLink or _manually_ adding an anchor tag has exactly the same result. When you click the link your browser will make **exactly** the same request to the server (routing will run, authorization, etc exactly the same way). In fact your answer reflects this, Url.Action returns an url and does nothing else. If it helps, in some scenarios you might need to use `Url.RouteUrl("Default", new {Controller="Home", Action="Index"})` if you have several routes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Solution is to use the Url.Action Method.

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home
    </a>
</li>
```

Hopefully it helps others.